# Is it possible to identify this chrysalis?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

At least I *believe* it's a chrysalis. I found it hanging from my gate the other day.

I'm in Western Arkansas:

[image]

[More photos here](https://goo.gl/photos/AELRbEsaj64ybuR47)

Comment: Could you provide approximate size? (or is it too late? :p). Also, if you have nay additional photos they would be helpful.

Comment: it's about 1.5". I actually posted this elsewhere, I forget the exact species but it's the kind that glues sticks and bark to itself as camouflage.

Comment: My guess is a bagworm (*Thyridopteryx ephemeraeformis*). University of Arkasnsas has a [page](http://www.uark.edu/ua/arthmuse/bagworm.html) about these "pests"

Comment: @theforestecologist yes, that was it

Comment: Wayne or @theforestecologist why don't you write an answer and mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the image and location, I'd say you've got the chrysalis of a **bagworm moth** (family [*Psychidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth)) or some related species of case-building moth.

There are over 1350 species of *Psychidae*, and I am not certain of the exact species.

Caterpillars of this family are known to create protective cases out of local debris. Because this debris can vary, so too will the appearance of the case. Different species likewise prefer to use different materials. Sticks, leaves, tree scales, etc. have all been known to be used in their chrysalii. As a result, Googling for images should produce a wide variety of chrysalis structures. Here is [one example](https://wilkes.ces.ncsu.edu/2014/06/is-that-a-bagworm/) using Eastern Redcedar scales in NC:

[image]

The University of Arkasnsas has a [locally-relevant page](http://www.uark.edu/ua/arthmuse/bagworm.html) about *Thyridopteryx ephemeraeformis*, one species that is often considered a "pest".