# What type of bug cocoon is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

My question is about these cocoon like things that are all over my house and fence in Florida (USA).  [image]

Comment: FL being Florida? Or Flanders? Why do Americans always assume... Ah, forget it.

Comment: @RHA It does not matter, these moths would be the same everywhere. And if you really want to know the answer to your question, it is because America is huge, and surrounded by only 2 other countries. Most Americans live a great distance from the border of these two countries. It is equally arrogant to assume that Americans are uniquely insensitive. People are the same, regardless of where they live, and are shaped by the circumstances that surround them (like geography)

Comment: It does matter, one should always be clear about location. See https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/are-there-any-guideline-about-species-identification-questions

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/51252/16866

Answer (score 2):

That is a bagworm. Order Lepidoptera, family Psychidae. You can read about them here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagworm_moth